# Uploading .nc file on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I have downloaded the netCDF plugin for GeoServer 2.15 and put it in its directory >> it had been shown on GeoServer as raster data >>
but while uploading .nc file by using this plugin I still have this error

> Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:gwc/psl_RF_1980-2005_monmean.nc and hints Hints: REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@7062ed2a EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@960bf8a[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] System defaults: FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@11acdc30

that can`t enable me to upload any data.

Comment: does geoserver have write permissions for the directory?

Comment: what does the log file say? after you turn logging up to GeoTools-Developer